# How to maintain the flow rate of Hario Woodneck cloth filters as they age?

Tags: filter, pour-over, maintenance

The Hario Woodneck brewer uses cloth filters that are not meant to last forever but I am looking to increase their usable age. As weeks pass, the flow rate of water through the filter noticeably slows down. In a brand new filter it seems almost constant from full to empty, but after a month or so the last bit takes ages to drain. What should I be doing to keep them 'alive' longer?

I am using the ones in the image if it matters. These are inserted to the hoop provided with the Woodneck.

[image]

Before first use I soak the filter in boiling water for a few minutes as instructed. After each use I rinse it with hot water. Between uses I store the filter in a ziplock bag in the freezer.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting a glob of coconut oil on the filter and then sprinkle a little baking soda and salt on too. Scrub with a stiff plastic toothbrush/nailbrush followed by a warm vinegar/lemon juice dosing, a final brushing, then a hot water rinse. This works well for ceramic mug coffee stains too :-)

Comment: What does the coconut oil do, exactly?

Comment: A portion of the coffee stain is oil based. Coconut oil will help dissolve that. In addition, coconut oil is naturally antibacterial and antiviral which is a good thing when cleaning something like this I think.